# ExcelApp.Visible causing Error 91 and I can't figure out how to fix it

Tags: excel, vba, autocad

A little background:
A former employee wrote a VBA program to run in AutoCAD to generate G-code based off of CAD entities. The immediate problem is that it currently only runs in AutoCAD 2002 on a computer running Windows XP on a virtual desktop. Obviously, that doesn't work so I'm trying to get it to work on BricsCad V21. My current issue is that I keep getting a Run time error 91 at the following place and I do not understand what the issue is or how to overcome it.

Please note that I am a VERY beginner programmer and am still trying to wrap my head around how all of this works. Any help you can provide would be most appreciated.

```
Public ExcelApp As Excel.Application
Public wbkObj As Excel.Workbook
Public shtObj As Excel.Worksheet
Public rngObj As Excel.Range
```

These are the relevant declarations at the beginning of the program

```
Sub CAM_A_CHEST()
Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wbkObj = ExcelApp.workbooks.Add
Set shtObj = ExcelApp.Worksheets(1)
If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Could not start Excel", vbExclamation
    End
Else
    ExcelApp.Visible = True
    Application.Visible = True
    ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set rngObj = shtObj.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 5))
    With rngObj
        .NumberFormat = "0"
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Font.Size = 10
        '.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With shtObj.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2000, 13))
        .NumberFormat = "0.000"
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Font.Size = 9
        .Value = ""
    End With
    With shtObj.Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(2000, 5))
        .NumberFormat = "0"
    End With
    shtObj.Range("A1:D1").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    shtObj.Cells(1, 1).ColumnWidth = 18
    shtObj.Cells(1, 1) = "Layer"
    shtObj.Cells(1, 2) = "Center X"
    shtObj.Cells(1, 3) = "Center Y"
    shtObj.Cells(1, 4) = "Diameter"
    shtObj.Cells(1, 5) = "Sort"
    shtObj.Cells(1, 7).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
    shtObj.Cells(1, 7).Font.Size = 10
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
End If
    
'ExcelApp.Visible = False
transZ$ = "2.00"

divNum$ = ""
grpNum$ = "0"

Load UserForm1
Load UserForm2
Load UserForm3
Load procUserForm

Call UserForm_Initialize
```

That is the chunk of code that opens Excel, formats the Worksheet, and prepares for inputs from AutoCAD. Later on in the code, The following Sub is called:

```
Sub CAM_TopAndBottomBoards()

    Dim I As Integer
    Dim mspaceObj As AcadObject
    Dim centerPoint As Variant
    Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application
    

increment = 0
Call InitializeCounters
SelectStuff:
'Find entities representing Pitman Holes, Pipe Holes, etc., among items selected,
'     dump data into Excel sheet
ExcelApp.Visible = True
```

It's that last line that is generating the error.

At this point I've spent a couple of days on this issue and I'm completely stuck. Help!

Comment: It was never set in `CAM_TopAndBottomBoards()`.

Comment: You have `Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application` but you never assign that variable to anything.  If you're trying to use the Global `ExcelApp` then you can't have the local declaration, since that will hide the Global.

Comment: I tried that and it sort of ran once. Now it generates Run Time Error 1004: Method 'Selection' of object '_Global' failed". That error shows up at `Set rngObj = shtObj.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 5))`

Comment: If I recall correctly, I added the local declarations to get the Error 1004 to go away